# Django | making searchform to filter with multiple models

Tags: python, django, search-form

I'm trying to create a search form in my Django project that will filter multiple models(3) It works for a single model and an additional model tied by a foreign key. But,I can not combine different models query to one get_queryset.

forms.py

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
username=forms.CharField(
    label = 'enterprise_id',
    required = False    
)
skill_name=forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Skill_name.objects,
    label='skill_list',
    required=False
)
```

model.py

```
    class EnterpriseID(models.Model):
    enterprise_id = models.CharField('enterprise_id',max_length=40,blank=True,default="",)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.enterprise_id

class Skill_name(models.Model):
    skill_name = models.CharField('skill_name',max_length=40,blank=False,null=False,)
    def __str__(self):
             return '{0}'.format(self.skill_name)

class Skill(models.Model):
    enterprise_id = models.ForeignKey(EnterpriseID,verbose_name="enterprise_id",on_delete=models.PROTECT,)
    skill_name=models.ForeignKey(Skill_name,verbose_name="skill_name",on_delete=models.PROTECT,)
    def __str__(self):
             return '{0}'.format(self.enterprise_id)

class Employee(models.Model):
    # user = models.OneToOneField(accounts_models.AuthUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    enterprise_id = models.ForeignKey(EnterpriseID,verbose_name="enterprise_id",on_delete=models.PROTECT,)

    join_at = models.DateField('join_at',default="",null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(self.enterprise_id)
```

views.py

```
class PersonalInfoSearchView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Employee
    template_name = 'personal_info/search_personal_info.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs) 
        context['form'] = SearchForm(self.request.GET) 
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        form = SearchForm(self.request.GET)
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        if form.is_valid():

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']   
            skill_name = form.cleaned_data['skill_name']

            if username:

                queryset=queryset.filter(enterprise_id__enterprise_id__icontains=username)

            if skill_name:
               skill_query =Skill.objects.filter(skill_name=skill_name)     
         return queryset.distinct()
```

Comment: Why you are returning ```HttpResponseRedirect``` in ```get_queryset()``` method ?

Comment: Sorry. I had mistakes for indents, in this get_queryset, it returns queryset.

Comment: use ```FormView``` instead of ```ListView```. It's possible even with ```ListView```, but ```FormView``` is way preferable for you.

Comment: I use Listview because I want to display the template on the same page as the search result.

Comment: ```FormView``` can do this also, of course. But, if you want to use ```ListView``` okay, just add ```Form``` validation logics in ```get()``` method and render template manually. You are validation ```Form``` in ```get_queryset()``` it's mistake.

Comment: OK, but my problem is not that, I want to filter Employee objects using by the form of "skill_name". And, I don't have any idea to connect between Skill_name Object and Employee Object.